# How to add env key and values in a dictionary for bash script

Tags: bash

I have two env variables

```
SMTP_PASSWORD=SMTP_PASSWORD_KEY
MICROSCANNER_TOKEN=MICROSCANNER_TOKEN_KEY
```

I need to add this to a dict using bash

**eg: arr["SMTP_PASSWORD"]=SMTP_PASSWORD_KEY**

the key and value should be taken from env

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside your script:

```
export SMTP_PASSWORD=mySMTPKey
export MICROSCANNER_TOKEN=myMicroscannerKey
```

Inside your script:

As individual variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
SMTP_PASSWORD=${SMTP_PASSWORD_KEY}
MICROSCANNER_TOKEN=${MICROSCANNER_TOKEN_KEY}
```

As a map (available in Bash 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A MYMAP 
MYMAP[SMTP_PASSWORD]=${SMTP_PASSWORD_KEY}
MYMAP[MICROSCANNER_TOKEN]=${MICROSCANNER_TOKEN_KEY}
```

To iterate over the external ENV and add key/value pairs:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A MYMAP
while IFS='=' read -r -d '' n v; do
    MYMAP[${n}]=${v}
done < <(env -0)

# display all variable key value pairs
for K in "${!MYMAP[@]}"; do 
    echo $K = ${MYMAP[$K]}; 
done
```

Given your last comment, not wanting to bring in all ENV vars, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
envArray=( SMTP_PASSWORD MICROSCANNER_TOKEN )

declare -A MYMAP
for k in "${envArray[@]}"; do
    MYMAP[$k]=${!k}
done

for K in "${!MYMAP[@]}"; do
    echo $K = ${MYMAP[$K]};
done
```

Comment: the issue is I don't know how to create a dict using env, I need to create a dict in bash with the env keys and values

Comment: Check the third option above.

Comment: working fine. can you please help me to take the key and values from a variable too  eg :var = SMTP_PASSWORD=SMTP_PASSWORD_KEY MICROSCANNER_TOKEN=MICROSCANNER_TOKEN_KEY

Comment: Loop through key values `for K in "${!MYMAP[@]}"; do echo $K = ${MYMAP[$K]}; done`

Comment: no , now the key and value is taken from env . i need to take the values from a var.eg:SMTP_PASSWORD=SMTP_PASSWORD_KEY MICROSCANNER_TOKEN=MICROSCANNER_TOKEN_KEY is from a var.in env there are so many unwanted keys and values so i grep the needed keys and values in a var

Comment: If you know what keys you need, then you should hard code them into the map using option 2.  There is no way for bash to guess which ENV variables you need

Answer (score 0):

You need an associative array (supported in `bash` 4 or later).

```
declare -A arr

arr[SMTP_PASSWORD]=$SMTP_PASSWORD
arr[MICROSCANNER_TOKEN]=$MICROSCANNER_TOKEN
```

There is no preexisting associative array that automatically includes all existing environment variables as its keys.

Comment: Yes. Why, though, do you need an associative array in the first place?